# Multiselect or Multicheck cannot select all

Tags: vb.net, devexpress

I have a problem with Select all or MultiSelect, it doesn't select all the table, I'm using Visual Basic (VB)

Is about to Select Them all with only one click on the button in the GridView

Is there a function that could be work of checks or selects?

Note: I'm running Visual Studio 2012 with Devexpress 15.2

```
GridView2.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = True
GridView2.OptionsSelection.MultiSelectMode = DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridMultiSelectMode.CheckBoxRowSelect
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XieUu.png)

Do I forgot something to add this code using VB NET?

```
Columns["ALTA"].ColumnEdit
```

Comment: Row selection has nothing to do with checking/unchecking the other check boxes in your grid, which I assume are bound to Boolean fields. That is setting the VALUE of them, not their selection status. As you can see in your image, all the selection column boxes (the first column) are selected.I believe what you want to do instead is loop through the rows in your grid and change the value of those fields.

Comment: yes, the grid should be selected all but, does it work to check all with 6 colums?

Comment: No. The GridView's [SelectAll method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridView.SelectAll.method) does not check your other 6 columns. The grid control would have no idea that it should check those just because you want to select rows. Instead you need to do what I suggested above: loop through the GridView and set the value for all six columns in each row.

Comment: how it would be in code or it would most probably not working the 6 columns check all with VB NET?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a for loop and then the GridView's [SetRowCellValue](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.ColumnView.SetRowCellValue.overloads) method to change the value of each checkbox column. You may also want to review the [Traversing Rows](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3484/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Views/Grid-View/Rows#traverse) documentation. For instance:

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridView1.DataRowCount; i++)
{
   gridView1.SetRowCellValue(i, "FieldName1", true);
   gridView1.SetRowCellValue(i, "FieldName2", true);
}


For i As Integer = 0 To gridView1.DataRowCount - 1
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(i, "FieldName1", True)
    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(i, "FieldName2", True)
Next
```

Comment: But if I use VB NET, how it would be?

Comment: I've updated my example with a VB.NET sample using one of the many online [C# to VB.NET converters.](http://converter.telerik.com/). I'd suggest you bookmark one to convert trivial code snippets such as this.

Comment: It worked fine for me, but that's not important. The updated snipped above should serve as the basis for looping through your grid's rows and updating each cell value.